Cool little saying in Kodoku No Gurume
In Kodoku No Gurume (孤独のグルメ) Season 4 Episode 4 Goro is saying a cool little saying (maybe an onomatopoeia thing?) that goes something like this:
ヒレハラホロヒレ、何これヒレハレ。
I've uploaded the excerpt to YouTube.
Is this a commonly known little saying or is it just made up? I would be very interesting in knowing more about it. Where does it come from? When do you use it? What exactly does it mean?

That is a parody of ハラホロヒレハレ, which is one of the signature gags of 谷啓 (1932-2010). It gained popularity in the 1960s and is still remembered by many as a classic Showa gag.
